# Unable to connect to Elasticsearch in ELK Docker container

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, ibm-cloud, kibana, elastic-stack

I've been following a tutorial (http://jamesthom.as/blog/2015/07/08/making-logs-awesome-with-elasticsearch-and-docker) describing how to deploy an ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) container to Bluemix. I've successfully built the container, and deployed it to the Bluemix registry, but when i start the container and access the Kibana dashboard, I get the following error message: 'Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://localhost:9200.'

Should the Elasticsearch URL be different, and it this is the case, where do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable for Elasticsearch Url when you run your Kibana container:

```
-e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://some-elasticsearch:9200
```

Or you can link your containers with `--link` parameter :

```
 --link some-elasticsearch:elasticsearch
```

And you can find more information from https://hub.docker.com/_/kibana/ or check the following lines:

> You can run the default kibana command simply:
>
> `$ docker run --link some-elasticsearch:elasticsearch -d kibana`
>
> You can also pass in additional flags to kibana:
>
> `$ docker run --link some-elasticsearch:elasticsearch -d kibana --plugins /somewhere/else`
>
> This image includes EXPOSE 5601 (default port). If you'd like to be able to access the instance from the host without the container's IP, standard port mappings can be used:
>
> `$ docker run --name some-kibana --link some-elasticsearch:elasticsearch -p 5601:5601 -d kibana`
>
> You can also provide the address of elasticsearch via ELASTICSEARCH_URL environnement variable:
>
> `$ docker run --name some-kibana -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://some-elasticsearch:9200 -p 5601:5601 -d kibana`
>
> Then, access it via http://localhost:5601 or http://host-ip:5601 in a browser.